# How to get parent class name, from child

Tags: c++

i have something similar configData:

```
class all {
public:
    class animals {
    public:
        class animalPatern {
        public:
            int hp = 80;
            std::string name = "no name";
        };
        class cow : public animalPatern {
        public:
            std::string name = "big cow";
        };
        class bird : public animalPatern {
        public:
            std::string name = "small bird";

        };
    };
};
```

how can i get parent class name **animalPatern** by children class **bird**, for template i can use **std::is_base_of**, cannot find some information how to do for class...
as well as the ability to get all child classes name, like **animals** have: **animalPatern,cow ,bird**

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do. In order to use `animalPatern`, just write down that identifier, there is no need to "get" it from anywhere. OTOH a parent cannot get any information about children.

Comment: sorry, bad translate, have name class "cow" get his parent name class "animalPatern"
I have several methods to get data in a concrete class, want try write metod to get parent class name, and get all class childrens

Comment: @hekut146 As a string at runtime or as the identifier at compile time. Also some things you should be aware of: 1. `bird` and `cow` objects contain 2 strings each 2. You can inherit from multiple classes which could complicate things, if it happened in your case.

Comment: Looks like `all` and `animals` should be `namespace` instead of empty `class`.

Comment: The computer has no need for silly things like human-readable identifiers. They are usually long gone, discarded as unnecessary by the compiler, at runtime.

Comment: This reads like [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you add why you need this information to the question and what you will use it for we may be able to offer alternatives.

Comment: this will be a simple config, only child : parent 
2.
just include class list
3.
all::animals::cow data;
int getInt = data.hp; //to get int member

Comment: My task: a simple game config file, simple editing of parameters, considering inheritance

Comment: to get a parent, the only thing that comes to my mind is clipping the text after receiving:
std::string configPath = typeid(data).name(); 2. That's the right decision?

Comment: `typeid` is not as helpful in this case as you would like. [`name` offers very few guarantees](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) and they don't include uniqueness or human readability..

Comment: can i use string (dynamic) argument for (this config path(variable type)) all::animals::cow?

Comment: and dynamic field like...: data.hp, sorry, i try googling 2 days, and maybe I am not correctly naming what I am talking about

Comment: in c# have getmember metod, but in c++... https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.getmember?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Why don't you use virtual functions? No need for `name` data; instead use a method `inline std::string name() const noexcept` that will simply return class'es name, like `{return "big cow";}`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i try to read. 2. I'm not sure if this is what I need, I just have the task of creating a gameConfigFile that supports inheritance